# How do I compile multiple protects c# into one

Tags: c#, reference, linker

Everyone.
Please I am new to c# program. I want to ask is it is possible to combine 3 separate independent programs to one executable file.
To explain what I mean:
program_1 has its' own .sln
program_2 has its' own .sln
program_2 has its' own .sln

,and I want to has a single .sln to output a single program.exe
They are all console APP.

Any guide would be highly appreciated

Comment: If you have 3 different console apps, you have 3 entry points. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Also, assemblies (i.e. .exe or .dll) are produced by *projects*. It is normal for a solution to contain multiple projects. But the main way to share code is in *libraries*, i.e. dll-files. The executables might be a very simple, and just delegate all the real work to a library function. So you really need to specify a bit more what you have done, and what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You should have one solution and many projects in that solution.One of the project have program.cs that class is start point of the entire solution.Usually you will see program.cs in the Console.app or WebApi etc or WinForm. **When you right click on solution instead of creating ConsoleApp create ClassLibrary Project**. But even your projects have different program.cs files you can use their classess in your other projects.

Comment: If understand your last statement "But even your projects have different program.cs files you can use their classess in your other projects." I can use the program.cs to create ClassLibrary project which can be easily used. Then create a console app project and reference the ClassLibrary projects

Comment: No , you should create one entry point (only one program.cs ) to not get confused.For example , you have 3 projects , 2 of them can be class library but one of them should be main project (api, desktop,mobile) .

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I am on it.